# Javascript won't change pages in PDF or Zoom

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, microsoft-edge

I'm using Windows 10 and I have a file called `pdf.html` on my Desktop.

The contents of `pdf.html` is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goAndZoom(pageNum,zoom)
{
    var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf');
    pdf.data = pdf.data+'#page='+pageNum+'&zoom='+zoom;
    document.body.removeChild(pdf);
    document.body.appendChild(pdf);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goAndZoom(4,300);">Go to Page 4 and zoom 300%</button>
<object id="pdf" data="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf" width="100%" height="700px" type="application/pdf">
<param name="zoom" value="100" />
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

I open this file in Chrome.  When I press the button "Go to page 4 and zoom 300%", the embedded pdf will go to page 4 and zoom 300%. When I repeat these two actions in Edge browser, the pdf stays on page 1 without altering the zoom.  I have shared this `pdf.html` file with other people and they reported the same problem when using IE 11.

How do I get the `goAndZoom()` function to go to a page in a PDF and zoom in IE and Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution exists as of April 27, 2016

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has weird behaviours when working with html objects. Try creating a new object using the same attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goAndZoom(pageNum,zoom)
{
    var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf');
    var newPdf = document.createElement("object");
    newPdf.type = "application/pdf";
    newPdf.height = pdf.height;
    newPdf.width = pdf.width;
    newPdf.id = pdf.id;
    newPdf.data = pdf.data+'#page='+pageNum+'&zoom='+zoom;
    document.body.removeChild(pdf);
    document.body.appendChild(newPdf);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="goAndZoom(4,300);">Go to Page 4 and zoom 300%</button>
<object id="pdf" data="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf" width="100%" height="700px" type="application/pdf">
<param name="zoom" value="100" />
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that still didn't work....MS Edge does not seem to respect the hash tag and other query string parameters on page load or via javascript manipulation

Comment: Even removing the code aspect, IE does not respect the hashtags in the URL after the settings have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here but here's the answer...

In IE, you're (probably) actually using Adobe Reader to display the PDF via the Reader plugin. While the PDF open parameters would work if the PDF were not already open in the viewer, they don't when you just append them to the same source. Reader knows the file is already open and ignores the open parameters. You'd need to set the data property to nothing first, then back to the URL with the parameters to get it to work.

For Edge... give up. It won't interpret the open parameters.